# Magento static block not displaying in 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

In the new version the block include in CMS is blocked. You have to set permissions first. We have used following:

System -> Permissions -> Blocks

There you add a new entry named cms/block and set them to Allowed. Then you get your blocks back.

But it's not working in Magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: In your static block or in cms page you might have another blocks used apart from cms/block.You have to white list all those blocks also.

Comment: Thanks we are create other block its working fine